# DynamoDB : Good practice to use a timestamp field in a Primary Key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I want to store and retrieve data from a DynamoDB table.

My data (an item = a review a user gave on a feature of an app) have the following attributes :

```
user        string 
feature     string
appVersion  string
timestamp   string 
rate        int   
description string
```

There is multiple features, on multiple versions of the app, and an user can give multiple reviews on these features. So I would like to use (`user`, `appVersion`, `feature`, `timestamp`) as a primary key.

But it does not seem to be possible to use that much attributes in a primary key in DynamoDB.

The first solution I implemented is to use `user` as a `Partition Key`, and a hash of (`appVersion`, `feature`, `timestamp`) as a `Sort Key` (in a new field named `reviewID`).

My problem is that, I want to retrieve an item for a given `user`, `feature`, `appVersion` without knowing the `timestamp` value (let's say I want the item with the latest `timestamp`, or the list of all items matching the 3 fields)

Without knowing the `timestamp`, I can't build the `Sort Key` necessary to retrieve my item. But if I remove the `timestamp` from the `Sort Key`, I will not be able to store multiple items having the same (`user`, `appVersion`, `feature`).

What would be the proper way to handle this usecase ?

I am thinking about using a hash of (`user`, `appVersion`, `feature`) as a `Partition Key`, and the `timestamp` as a `Sort Key`, would this be a correct solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the timestamp at the end of your SK and then when you Query the data you use begins_with on the SK.

```
PK       SK
UserID   appVersion#feature#timestamp
```

This will allow you to dynamically query the data. For example you want all the users votes for a specific appversion

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE PK= 'x' AND SK BEGINS_WITH('{VERSION ID}')
```

This is done using a Query command.

Comment: In this case, how can I retrieve the item with the latest `timestamp` ? I should retrieve all items `WHERE PK= 'x' AND SK BEGINS_WITH('{VERSION ID}#{FEATURE ID}')`, and then find the latest one in my code ?

Comment: You would only be able to get the latest item for a given appVersion + feature. Strings are sorted in lexicographical order in ASC order in DynamoDB, so you would pass the param `ScanIndexForward=FALSE` and `Limit=1` to reverse the sort order and only return 1 item.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Lee Hannigan will work, I like it.

However, keep in mind that accessing a PK is very fast because its hash-based.

> I am thinking about using a hash of (user, appVersion, feature) as a
> Partition Key, and the timestamp as a Sort Key, would this be a
> correct solution?

This might also work, the table would look like this

```
PK                                                     SK
User#{User}AppVersion#{appVersion}#Feature#{feature}   TimeStamp#{timestamp}
```

If you always know the user, appVersion, and the feature, this will be more optimal, because the SK lookup is O(logN)

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
HASH string "modelName": "user"
RANGE string "id": "b0d5be50-4fae-11ed-981f-dbffcc56c88a"
```

uuid himself can be used for as timestamp

when searching you could search using reverse index

---

Another way

```
HASH string "modelName": "user"
RANGE string "createdAt" "2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z"
```

createdAt, use time format rfc3339

when searching you could search using reverse index

---

Put down on paper what you need and you'll find others way to manage indes HASH/RANGE